# Why was ViewController instance released when its view still in another view's subview list?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

point 1. in delegate:

```
self.friendListVC = [[FriendListVC alloc] init];
```

point 2.
in FriendCollectionVC.mm:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    FriendCollectionVC *friendCollectionVC = [[FriendCollectionVC alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:friendCollectionVC.view];
}
```

point 3. run:
use lldb:

```
po [self collectionView].delegate
p [self collectionView]
```

result:
[no Objective-C description available]
(PSTCollectionView *) $6 = 0x212bc400

point 4. continue run.
use lldb:

```
po [self collectionView].delegate
p [self collectionView]
```

result:

```
2013-11-30 00:15:25.637 App[45683:70b] *** -[FriendCollectionVC respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x67259eb0
[no Objective-C description available]
(PSTCollectionView *) $6 = 0x6785eca0
```

and use lldb at the same time:

```
po ((MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).friendListVC.view
<UIView: 0x6656efa0; frame = (0 0; 945 748); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x665d0fd0>>
```

point 5. Question:
Why the friendCollectionVC inside FriendListVC was released?
The AppDelegate and AppDelegate.friendListVC and AppDelegate.friendListVC.view are all available.
The friendListVC.view contains subview friendCollectionVC.view.  - see code 2.
And the project is using ARC.

Comment: Have you added self.friendListVC = [[FriendListVC alloc] init]; to the superview? Have you done anything with it except from [[alloc]init]?

Answer (score 1):

You are not keeping any strong pointer to friendCollectionVC, since you create it as a local variable. Adding its view as a subview doesn't do anything to change that fact. In any case, it's not a good idea to just add one controller's view as a subview of another controller's view.  When you add friendCollectionVC's view as a subview of FriendListVC's view, you should make friendCollectionVC a child view controller of FriendListVC, using the custom container controller api. If you do that, FriendListVC will have a strong pointer (in its childViewControllers array) to friendCollectionVC.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    FriendCollectionVC *friendCollectionVC = [[FriendCollectionVC alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:friendCollectionVC];
    [friendCollectionVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:friendCollectionVC.view];
}
```